# MySQL: Select categories, subcategories and brands. Only if they exist

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
brands(id, name)
categories(id, name)
subcategories(id, category_id, name)
```

plus a products table

```
products(id, category_id, subcategory_id, brand_id, [...])
```

I need to build a three-level menu and I am having a hard time doing it without querying the DB too many times.
Basically the menu is like this

```
Electronics -> Smartphones -> Samsung
```

My difficulty is creating a tree as the one above. I can't have for example `Electronics -> Smartphones -> Nike(I have Nike as a brand, but in this category/subcategory combo Nike is obviously not needed)`.

So far I end up with loops inside loops to only fetch the brands that exists for each combo, but that drastically increases the load time.

Is there a more efficient way of doing it ?

In the end I would like to have something like the following

```
Electronics
   Smartphones
      Samsung
      Apple
   TVs
      Samsung
      Lg
Shoes
   Sneakers
      Nike
      Converse
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select based on products table (to have no empty category/subcategory or brand)
Grouped by brand and subcategory (no need to have several lines with the same "combo" as we don't need the products info to be displayed here)
Ordered by alphabetical order (do as you want here)

```
$sql = 'SELECT b.id AS brand_id, b.name AS brand_name, sc.id AS subcategory_id, sc.name AS subcategory_name, c.id AS category_id, c.name AS category_name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN brand b ON p.brand_id = b.id
INNER JOIN subcategory sc ON p.subcategory_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN category c ON sc.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.brand_id, p.subcategory_id
ORDER BY c.name ASC, sc.name ASC, b.name ASC';
```

Then in PHP :

```
$lastCategoryId = 0;
$lastSubCategoryId = 0;

// Fetch results
while($result = // Fetch row) {
    if ($result->category_id != $lastCategoryId) {
    // This is the first time you see that category: display its name (and create a ul tag for example)
        echo '<br />'.$result->category_name.'<br />';
        $lastCategoryId = $result->category_id;
    }
    if ($result->subcategory_id != $lastSubCategoryId) {
    // This is the first time you see that subcategory: display its name (and create a sub-ul tag for example)
        echo '---'.$result->subcategory_name.'<br />';
        $lastSubCategoryId = $result->subcategory_id;
    }

    // No need to check the last brand_id because in the SQL we can't have the same subcategory/brand twice, so it will always be a new brand for this subcategory.
    echo '------'.$result->brand_name.'<br />';
}
```

*Edit : With nested ul/li (not tested)

```
$lastCategoryId = 0;
$lastSubCategoryId = 0;

// Main list
echo '<ul>';

while($result = // Fetch row) {

    // Category level
    if ($result->category_id != $lastCategoryId) {
    // First time you see that category
        // Re-init subcategory last id (so that later we can know if it's the first subcategory in this category or not)
        $lastSubCategoryId = 0;

        // Close previous category li (if $lastCategoryId == 0, means that there is no category to close, it's our very fist)
        if ($lastCategoryId != 0) {
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }

        // Open li element (which will contain category name + list of subcategories)
        echo '<li>';
        echo $result->category_name;

        // Open sub-ul (which will contain subcategories list)
        echo '<ul>';
    }

    // Subcategory level
    if ($result->subcategory_id != $lastSubCategoryId) {
    // First time you see that subcategory
        // Close previous subcategory li (if $lastSubCategoryId == 0, means that there is no subcategory to close, it's our first one in that category)
        if ($lastSubCategoryId != 0) {
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }

        // Open li element (which will contain subcategory name + list of brands)
        echo '<li>';
        echo $result->subcategory_name;

        // Open sub-sub-ul (which will contain brands list)
        echo '<ul>';
    }

    echo '<li>'.$result->brand_name.'</li>';
}

// Close last subcategory
echo '</ul></li>';

// Close last category
echo '</ul></li>';

// Closing main list
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: This worked great, I have to study it better to understand it but this is it. The only thing is, in the second if() it's $result->subcategory_name not $result->category_name. Thank you very much!

Comment: Right, I edited my post to fix the `subcategory_name` line. You might want to execute the SQL query in a phpMyAdmin tool (or similar) to see the result, you will better understand the PHP code then.

Comment: As a follow up question, how would you go about doing nested ul/li from your posted code ? I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: Hi, sorry I left before seeing your question yesterday. I edited my answer and tried something for the ul/li. I didn't test it at all (I hadn't time this morning) so it might need some fixes, have a close look to the HTML source to check if every tag has been well closed etc. :)

Comment: thanks for the update, but I found a solution in the meantime. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure a query with an inner join is all you need, unless you have some way of mapping a brand to multiple categories/subcategories.

```
select c.name, sc.name, b.name
from brands b
inner join subcategories sc where sc.id = b.subcategory_id
inner join categories c where c.id = b.category_id
```

This will build results like

```
Electronics    Smartphones    Samsung
Electronics    Smartphones    Apple
...
Shoes          Sneakers       Nike
```

etc.  If you really need that tree-style view, there are other options you can use to format it, but you should be able to pack the results into a nice data structure.